# PyDev not installing properly to eclipse 2023

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I recently downloaded eclipse 2023 to code in python. I downloaded python then went to ad Pydev to eclipse. After install Pydev never appeared as a create a project option or appeared in the window preferences. Eclipse says Pydev is installed yet I cannot use it.
[Projects Available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXwCR.png)
[Available preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTjNM.png)

I tried to uninstall and reinstall pydev to no avail. I even deleted eclipse and attempted to reinstall yet pydev still did not appear as an option after download. [Pydev is downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhKbQ.png)

I then I made sure I had Java 8 installed and restarted eclipse. No progress

Next I downloaded Eclipse Enterprise for Java and tried to get Pydev to work in their expecting it to work with no such luck.

Finally I attempted to add the zip file to plugins to see if that would work with no luck.[my installed zip file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQiK6.png)

Solution:
For those who might wonder. the error was never fully found. The solution that worked was a full reset of my computer then redownload of eclipse.

Comment: The issue seems to be that pydev needs java 8 but Eclipse runs on java 11 or greater. Having java 8 installed does not help since pydev lives by Eclipse's java version, as it seems.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.